# How to Transfer a BigQuery view to a Google Cloud Storage bucket as a csv file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I need to export the content of a BigQuery view to the csv file in GCP, with Airflow DAG. To export the content of the BQ TABLE, I can use BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator. But in my case I need to use an existing view, and BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator fails with this error, which I see while checking the logs for failed DAG:

> BigQuery job failed: my_view is not allowed for this operation because it is currently a VIEW

So, what options do I have here? I can't use a regular table, so may be there is another operator that would work with a view data stored in BQ, instead of table? Or may be the same operator would work with some addition options (although I don't see anything useful in here [Apache documentation for BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_to_gcs/index.html))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `Bigquery` client doesn’t give the possibility to export a view to a `GCS` file.

It’s not perfect but I propose you 2 solutions

**First solution (more native with existing operators) :**

- Create a staging table to export it to `GCS`
- At the beginning of your DAG, create a task that `truncate` this staging table
- Add a task with a `select` on your view and an `insert` in your staging table (`insert/select`)
- Use the `bigquery_to_gcs` operator from your staging table

**Second solution (less native with Python clients and PythonOperator) :**

- Use a `PythonOperator`
- In this operator, use a `Bigquery` Python client to load data from your view as Dict and the `storage` Python client to generate a file to `GCS` from this Dict

I have a preference for the first solution, even if it forces me to create a staging table.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a kind of combined solution, part of it is what Mazlum Tosun suggested in his answer: in my DAG I added an extra first step, a `DataLakeKubernetesPodOperator`, which runs a Python file. In that Python file there are calls to SQL files, which contain simple queries (put in the `await asyncio.wait(...)` block and executed with bq_execute() ): truncate an existing table (to prepare it for a new data), and then copy (insert) data from the view to the truncated table (as Mazlum Tosun suggested).

After that step, the rest is the same as before: I use `BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator` to copy data from the regular table (which now contains data from the view) to google cloud storage bucket, and now it works fine.